# Why does WMI skip some services on ASP.NET page?

Tags: asp.net, service, wmi

I am trying get all local machine services.

But why are some services missing from [`Win32_Service`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394418(VS.85).aspx) class?

[image: WMI asp.net issue]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The services are not returned in alphabetical order. You need to sort your results otherwise you will have to hunt through the list to find them. They are all there in my tests.

My sample code:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher mos = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_Service");
foreach (ManagementObject service in mos.Get())
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(service["DisplayName"]);
}
listBox1.Sorted = true;
```

Comment: Thank you. I noticed it and fixed the problem but forgot to update the answer.